# What does a rep loss for "user was removed" mean?

Tags: support, reputation

Today I lost rep with the following notation:

> -10        8 mins ago     removed     User was removed

What does this mean?  Some user had up-voted one of my answers (or two of my questions) and was then deleted, and the votes go away with the user?

When a vote is removed you get told what post was affected, but here there is no such information.  I'm not worried about the rep; I'm just curious what happened.

Comment: OY! I lost 90 points!

Comment: @DoubleAA, yeah, I think removing votes damages the community, just as removing a deleted user's posts would.  Both contribute to the best content bubbling up.  The link in HodofHod's answer makes for interesting reading.

Comment: Funny thing - I *gained* 5 points :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A certain user requested that his account be deleted. This leaves all of his posts intact, but removes his user, and apparently his votes, both up and down.

See [What does “user was removed” mean and why did I lose 5 reputation for it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126470/what-does-user-was-removed-mean-and-why-did-i-lose-5-reputation-for-it)

Comment: ⁪⁪⁪⁪⁪⁪⁪⁪⁪⁪⁪⁪⁪⁪⁪ V'd"l

Comment: A mod could delete without a trace?

Comment: @ShmuelBrill I believe it's possible, but it wasn't done in this case.

Comment: I'm referring to the name that was removed from this post.

Comment: @ShmuelBrill No, I just removed it within the 5 minute grace period.

Comment: Is there a publicly available reason why he left?